# FFmpeg is Not Working on my Electron Angular app

Tags: angular, ffmpeg, electron

This previously working FFMPEG implementation, is no longer successful on my updated Angular 14 Electron 19 project. The getAudiVolume will exit with this error: " `An error occurred while analysing: Output format null is not available`"

#### IMPLEMENTING NORMALISATION

The component method

```
downloadYoutube(id: string){
  const filename = id+'.mp4';
  const filepath = Config.homePath? Config.homePath + '/' + filename : filename;
  const stream =  ytdl(id).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
      stream.on('finish', (data) => {
        console.log(stream);
        this.mediaService.getAudioVolumes(stream).subscribe((d) => {console.log('done', d);});
      });
}
```

The service

```
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg-corrected';
import * as ffmpegBin from 'ffmpeg-static-electron';
import FS from 'fs';
import {Readable} from 'stream';
import {Config} from "../shared/config";

export interface IVolumes {
meanVolume: string;
maxVolume: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class MediaService {
  ffmpegPath = ffmpegBin.path
  .replace('app.asar/bin', 'app.asar.unpacked/' + this.binPath)
  .replace('node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/renderer/bin', this.binPath)
  .replace('browser/javascript', 'mac/x64') // TODO: platform hardcoded!
  ;

getAudioVolumes(stream: Readable | FS.WriteStream): Observable<IVolumes> {
  if (!Config.isElectron){
  this.ffmpegPath= 'node_modules/ffmpeg-static-electron/bin/mac/x64/ffmpeg';
  }
  ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(this.ffmpegPath);
  
      return new Observable((observer: NextObserver<IVolumes>) => {
        const that = this;
        ffmpeg(stream)
          .withAudioFilter('volumedetect')
          .addOption('-f', 'null')
          .audioBitrate(128)
  
          .on('progress', function(progress) {
            console.log('Normalising Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done');
          })
  
          .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('An error occurred while analysing: ' + err.message);
            observer.error('DBs are not accessible');
          })
  
          .on('end', (stdout: any, stderr: string) => {
            const max = that.parseVolume(stderr, 'max_volume:');
            const mean = that.parseVolume(stderr, 'mean_volume:');
            console.log('volume analysis done, MeanDB is ', mean);
            observer.next({meanVolume: mean, maxVolume: max});
            observer.complete();
          })
          .save('/dev/null');
      });
}
```

#### TRY IT:

1. Fork https://github.com/arcovoltaico/angular-electron
2. Check out on the branch yt-dl
3. run npm install on the root and also inside app/
4. We need to hack the following node modules package.json by adding :

- **fluent-ffmpeg-corrected**
  `"browser": { "fs": false, "child_process": false }`,
- **isexe**:
  `"browser": { "fs": false}`

5. Build the app by `npm run electron:build`
6. Execute the app (releases/xxx) and click the Download Kraftwerk Button, you will see the error  `An error occurred while analysing: Output format null is not available`

Comment: Have you ensured that the server/local machine  has the FFmpeg executable files already present ?

Comment: Hi, the point is not to need to install it but to have it embedded in the Electron app. I already achieved it on a previous Electron and Angular version project, with the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debug I realize that the problem was in the `utils.js` file on the `fluent-ffmpeg` library, when it compares the `instanceof Buffer` it always says `false` because the Buffer created is a browserified Buffer instead of a strict node Buffer.

Why was this the error?, well, when you try to use the ffmpeg commands the library will check that the format passed (`null` in this case) is one of the available ones, it does this by running `ffmpeg -formats` wich returns, you guessed it, a Buffer (as any other ffmpeg command), so the validation was always saying that the format you passed was not "valid".

How you can fix this?, you can manually edit the `node_modules` by hand, changing the condition -maybe- to `str.buffer instanceof ArrayBuffer`. But a cleaner solution might be adding the Buffer as a pollyfil in the webpack config, like this:

- Install buffer as a dev dependency `npm install buffer -D`
- Add the following code on the `angular.webpack.js` in the plugins section

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
...
        config.plugins = [
        ...config.plugins,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
        new NodePolyfillPlugin({
              excludeAliases: ["console"]
        })
    ];
```

Not sure if it works on all cases but with that you can do the build command and check that the error is gone.

Another thing:

- I realize that you are passing a `WriteStream` to ffmpeg which is odd as it should be a `ReadStream`, so maybe you will need to change that line to something like

```
  ffmpeg(FS.createReadStream((stream as any).path)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much. I have committed your fixes. Unfortunately, when clicking on the first download button, I still get an error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isStream'".  What is missing?  The goal is to get the analysed volume dB printed on the console and no errors. Cheers

Comment: I will take a look, but are you passing the stream as a readable stream (or file)? `ffmpeg(FS.createReadStream(stream.path)` or `ffmpeg(stream.path)` instead of just `ffmpeg(stream)`?

Comment: The problem is on BasicDownlad I can not pipe to CreateReadStream instead  of to  CreateWriteStream. But the stream.path fixed it, as I commit it now :-)

Comment: Yes!, because the stream is already finished the ffmpeg cant do much, so passing the path as a file should work!. Does it work now?

Comment: I'm cleaning up the project and come back to you ASAP, but I feel optimistic :-)

Comment: I think the ffmpeg is solved. Would you want to check the next error? I can set another bounty if you consider it.  Cheers ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74753891/why-ytdl-does-not-work-inside-an-observable

Comment: Good news!, yes please so we can close this bounty. I will also look into the other problem