# Electron image assets not accessible from build app

Tags: electron, electron-builder

As a proof of concept, I have added a mobile phone image to my HomeComponent on my Angular Eclectron 19 app, that it's perfectly visible when I run it by `npm start`

```
<img src="../../assets/mobile.png" height="100" width="auto"/>
```

I have tried different additions to electron-builder.json

```
{
  "asar": true,
  "directories": {
    "output": "release/"
  },
  "files": [
    "**/*",
    "!**/*.ts",
    "!*.map",
    "!package.json",
    "!package-lock.json",
    {
      "from": "../dist",
      "filter": ["**/*"]
    }
  ],
```

or package.json, to make the assets folder available outside the asar build file.

Any idea about the needed configuration? Cheers

Images loaded on the packaged app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular tends to solve that for you, did you try to use `assets/mobile.png` instead of `../../assets/mobile.png`?

Comment: So definitely not a builder issue, but a different behavior on Electron.  So lucky of having your help. Cheers !!!!